# Entity Relationship Diagram Sales

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, entity-relationship, erd

I wanted to ask your opinion on the following ERD diagram i made. Keep in mind that i haven't already represented the cardinality of the relations yet.

[image]

What i'm going for is:

- A client goes in to buy a car;
- The car can be upgraded with many extras which add up to the base price of the car;
- The salesman can offer extras at no cost or offer a discount on the sale's total price in order to captivate clients;

What do you think of my diagram? Is it right? Do you see anything wrong?

**[EDIT]**

How do i go about representing the following scenario. A customer sells me a used car as a part of a purchase of a new car.

Comment: Just asking... If the discount is given on the sale's total price, then why the `discount` attribute is present in `OrderDetails`? Why not in `Order`?

Comment: to offer an extra at no cost (100% discount). But again, i don't know it's the correct way to do things.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. But what if salesman wants to give a discount on overall cost? Where do you plan to store that information? (Not sure if that is a valid business scenario in your case)

Comment: Next, the attribute `SalesTotal` - This can be calculated based on the prices of `Car` and `Extra` minus `Discount`... Is there any reason to Keep this column as an extra attribute?

Comment: The discount on he overall cost goes in the Order entity (table). I thought i had put it there :(
Th reason why i put price as an extra attribute is because extra's change price at any given point. Bu i should be ale to break down the sale enough to see the original price of stuff at that date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether your model is right or not depends on whether your model can capture all the business scenarios you described above - and IMHO, your model does that quite well (*Congratulation!*); barring few small anomalies such as, not having the `Discount` attribute in `Order` entity to capture overall discount on sales (which is a possible business scenario).

But when you create model like this, you should consider the final purpose of this model:

- Is it for capturing transactional data (**OLTP**)?
- Is it for storing data for reporting purpose (**OLAP**)

In your case, I believe your final goal is to capture business transactions by designing on *Online Transaction Processing* (OLTP) system. OLTP models are generally normalised in nature (due to the obvious benefits of normalisation such as reduced redundancy, update/ delete anomaly prevention etc.) Your model is mostly in **3NF** form, except for few transitive dependencies. The column `SalesTotal` in entity `Order` appears to be a derivable column (based on `Price` and `Discount` which you have already stored in other entities) and, IMO, need not be separately maintained (read *redundant*).

Also based on your comment above,

> extra's change price at any given point. Bu i should be ale to break
>   down the sale enough to see the original price of stuff at that date

I don't think you will be able to do it because your `Extra` entity is designed to store the current `Price` always. Your `OrderDeatils` contain the relationship between `Car` and `Extra` for any given point in time. If the prices of car and extra changes later, you will lose the old value as you will update the old price with new price. Hence, although you will be able to track the `ID_Car` and `ID_Extra` from `OrderDetails`, you won't know what were their historical prices during the time of order creation.

If you want to store historical prices, consider adding one more table each with `Car` and `Extra` to store past prices against dates.

> client can act as a seller

In the situation when a client can act as a seller, the person will exist independently in both your `Client` and `Salesman` table... That's perfectly alright (Such design technique is called *Vertical Separation*).

Alternatively, if you really need a 3NF model, then you should create a new entity - `Person` containing attributes such as `name`, `id` etc. This `Person` entity will be used to store both your client and salesman details as technically both of them are some person, but their "role" is different. Once you have this `Person` entity, you can delete `SalesMan` and `Client` entities. Then in the `Order` entity, you already have a `Clent ID` and a `Salesman ID` attribute to define the relationship between two different persons (These `Clent ID` and `Salesman ID` will be `Foreign Key` to the `Person ID` in `Person` entity). Whether a person is playing the role of a salesman or a client can be known from `Order` entity.

Hope this helps

Comment: Nicely put @hashbrown. Very elucidative and clear. One thing i haven't been able to capture, and it's a definite plausible scenario, is that a client can act as a seller to my stand. How should i represent this? I mean, instead of me being the seller a person may come in at any time and offer to sell me a new/used car.

Comment: @MossEverett Updated my above answer with the point you raised

Comment: @MossEverett If you like my answer, do not forget to 'Up Vote' / 'Accept' this as answer :-)